# How to dynamically choose subclass from inherited class while defining global methods

Tags: python, class, static-methods, factory-pattern

This is my first real foray into Python classes, so please excuse any misuse of terms.

I'm trying to use the [Factory Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) approach to choosing a subclass dynamically, based on a URL provided by the user. Here's the setup I have:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

class Templates(object):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0'}
        self.url = url

    def url(self):
        return self.url

    def response(self):
        return self.response

    def text(self):
        return self.text

    def dom(self):
        return self.dom

    @staticmethod
    def get_template(url):
        headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0'}
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        text = response.text
        if 'Website by Dealer.com' in text:
            return Dealer(url)
        else:
            return None

class Dealer(Templates):
    def __init__(self, url):
        Templates.__init__(self, url)
        self.new_vehicle_url = "{}/new-inventory/index.htm".format(self.url.rstrip('/'))
        self.used_vehicle_url = "{}/used-inventory/index.htm".format(self.url.rstrip('/'))
```

What I want to be able to do is call `Templates.get_template(url)` and have it return the appropriate subclass. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273568/pick-a-subclass-based-on-a-parameter) made it look really easy, but I'm missing something in the process because I also want to define general methods in my `Templates` class, which requires me to pass `url` to `Template`.

What is the Pythonic way of setting this up such that the following code will work?

```
template = Templates().get_template(url) # assume returns Dealer()
template.url
# 'http://www.some-website.com'
template.response.status_code
# 200
```

Comment: Why is `Templates.get_template(url)` not working?

Comment: Anyway, normally you would use a `classmethod` instead of a `staticmethod`. Quite frankly, the only times I see the use of `staticmethod` is from people coming from languages like Java, that don't allow module-level functions, and can't shake the habit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you use `Templates()` but that actually tries to create an instance of `Templates` - which fails because it's missing the `url` parameter for in `Templates.__init__`.

But you don't need an instance to call a staticmethod:

```
template = Templates.get_template(url) # assume returns Dealer()
template.url
# 'http://www.some-website.com'
template.response.status_code
# 200
```

I just removed the `()` after `Templates` there.

Comment: It's always something simple... thanks for the help!

Comment: @brittenb No problem. I'm glad to help :)